# Multithreading while call-back to a function

Tags: java, multithreading

Ok this could be a very big question.

I have one service(say notifier) and one of method [say notifyTransaction(Transaction trans) ] of this service  is remotely available for callbacks.

Now there is other service say (transactionsReader) which keeps reading incoming transactions and calls up the remote method of notifier that is `notifyTransaction(Transaction trans).`

Now to explain you the problem, I would like to add that my transaction contains more than one Operations. And for treating operations i have one function say `processOperation(Operation op).`

This `processOperation(Operation op)` actually do some updates on a database.

Whats the problem ?
  The service transactionsReader is reading incoming transactions at very fast speed and calling up the `notifyTransactions()` at the speed much greater than the speed of processing operations by `processOperation(Operation op)` method.

What I want to do ?
 I want to use multithreadint in `notifyTransactions()` so that I have multiple threads to treat every transaction.

For starting I used 
`ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);`
in the method `notifyTransactions()` and created task of my method processOperation(Operation op). But this creates a different pool for every call to `notifyTransactions()` so I had somewhere around 3000 pools in few seconds. And finally it went Out of Memory.

What could be other possible solutions ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For starting I used ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2); in the method notifyTransactions()

This is the issue you need `ExecutorService` instance to be common in both. If you start invoking per operation then it will create large number of threads. You should just call `submit` task inside `notifyTransactions()`

You should use a producer consumer approach using [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) which is bounded. So if queue is full producer will stop if queue is empty consumers will stop.
So in your case `processOperation(Operation op)` is a producer which will process operation and put it in BlockingQueue and inside `notifyTransactions()` you will dequeue it and process accordingly.

Comment: +1 If you want to inject your own blocking queue then you should instantiate the `ThreadPoolExceutor` directly: `new ThreadPoolExecutor(nThreads, nThreads, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1000));`

Comment: Yes. But he has made a big mistake invoking threadpool each time. as you said it needs to be invoked only once like this.